# Report RDLC export excel The document is corrupt and cannot be opened

Tags: rdlc

I've deployed an mvc application where I'm using rdlc reports.
The application works ok
except for some computer where at the moment of exporting rdlc via Excel
[image]

user get the error 
The document is corrupt and cannot be opened 
I think it's related to Excel or firewall configuration on these computer.

Have you ever encountered a similar issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I am also facing this issue, Please tell how you have rectified this problem ?

Comment: This website is running on a intranet.the problem was due to the proxy server that was blocking the download of the file. The site manager managed to solve and the file became downloadable again.